# Android geocoding api can't return addressess

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding

I'm having some trouble geocoding locations, i guess i've implemented everything. I've registered a google api, i've recieved a working google Api key, i also turned on google maps and geocoding services, but i can't get any locations associated with some hardcoded longitudes and latitudes.

Here's the code:
    My AppLocationService

```
public class AppLocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

protected LocationManager locationManager;
Location location;

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE = 10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE = 1000 * 60 * 2;

public AppLocationService(Context context) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

public Location getLocation(String provider) {
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
        if (locationManager != null) {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            return location;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

My LocationAddress class

```
public class LocationAddress {
private static final String TAG = "LocationAddress";

public static void getAddressFromLocation(final double latitude, final double longitude,
                                          final Context context, final Handler handler) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
            String result = null;
            try {
                List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        latitude, longitude, 1);
                if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                    Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    }
                    sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                    sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                    sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                    result = sb.toString();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable connect to Geocoder", e);
            } finally {
                Message message = Message.obtain();
                message.setTarget(handler);
                if (result != null) {
                    message.what = 1;
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    result = "Latitude: " + latitude + " Longitude: " + longitude +
                            "\n\nAddress:\n" + result;
                    bundle.putString("address", result);
                    message.setData(bundle);
                } else {
                    message.what = 1;
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    result = "Latitude: " + latitude + " Longitude: " + longitude +
                            "\n Unable to get address for this lat-long.";
                    bundle.putString("address", result);
                    message.setData(bundle);
                }
                message.sendToTarget();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

}

Somewhere deep in my mainActivity:

```
appLocationService = new AppLocationService(
            ServerInterface.this);

    Location location = appLocationService
            .getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


    if (location != null) {
        double latitude = 47.162494;
        double longitude = 19.503304;
        LocationAddress locationAddress = new LocationAddress();
        LocationAddress.getAddressFromLocation(latitude, longitude,
                getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandler());
    }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take look at [this](http://javapapers.com/android/android-get-address-with-street-name-city-for-location-with-geocoding/). I tried and it worked.

Hope it hopes.

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: This is exactly the same project i copied to my code :) So if it works for you, it should work for me... i'll check everything again tomorrow.